# how can i change the hash code of java class?

Tags: java, hashmap

My doubt is, i have employee class which contains two variable id and name as follows:

```
public class EmpBean {
  int id=10;;
  String name="uday";
}
```

I have added this object into HashMap as follows:

```
HashMap<EmpBean, EmpBean> hashMap= new HashMap<EmpBean, EmpBean>();
hashMap.put(empBean, empBean);
```

Then:`System.out.println(hashMap.get(empBean).id);`

> OutPut:10;

When i call the `get()` method of `hashMap`,it calculates the hashcode and apply hashing on that and finds the bucket and returns the value.

so far this is fine.

If i want to change the hash code of my object before calling the get() method.
How can i do ?
I tried with `empBean.id=2000;`
But there is no change in hashcode.

Comment: the hashCode is generated by the method `hashCode` try overwriting that method

Comment: Hash codes **must not** change.

Comment: Perhaps override `hashCode`? This is Java 101 question, instead of asking SO you should first read any introductory Java book.

Answer (score 2):

If you change value in object witch is in HashMap you must first remove item from HashMap then edit value and after then insert into HashMap again.

Comment: No, you don't have to remove it from Lists. You should do it however if you're using hash based data structures such as HashMap, if you want to find your object later again.

Comment: yes of corse. but hi use HashMap<EmpBean, EmpBean> hashMap= new HashMap<EmpBean, EmpBean>();

Comment: That's why Lists are irrelevant here. Maybe you want to edit your answer. Currently it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override hashCode and equals.  Joshua Bloch tells you how to do it properly in chapter 3 of "Effective Java".

Your EmpBean is using the Object hashCode implementation.  That won't change if you change values.

You should not be changing the hash code before calling the get method.

Answer (score 0):

this would be the hashCode Method generated by eclipse:

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + id;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}
```